# how to fix error Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry ValueOptions' in c#

Tags: c#, registry

I want to get date time which is saved in registry.So I prepared function named  `HandlemyRegistry()` I successfully inserted `DateTime` in registry by using following code.

But its showing error

> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to
>   'Microsoft.Win32.Registry ValueOptions' c#

I already tried many functions from google but not found good result

```
DateTime firstRunDate;
private bool HandlemyRegistry()
{
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\mySettings");
    key.SetValue("Set", "firstRunDate");
    key.Close();

    if (firstRunDate == default(DateTime))
    {
        firstRunDate = System.DateTime.Today.Date;
        Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue(@"SOFTWARE\mySettings", "Set", firstRunDate);
    }
    else if ((DateTime.Now - firstRunDate).Days > 20)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So you've included 3 *version specific* tags. I doubt that your code shown has some *specific* problem exhibited in *those three versions and only those versions*. If you have no reason to think it's a version specific issue, you should just use the [tag:c#] tag

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion

Comment: Are you using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) method?

Comment: You are doing both setting and getting totally wrong, indifferent of the content you want. Have you looked at the registry content after you stored the value? `firstRunDate` will be the value stored. Do you really want this?

Comment: I want to compare todays date with first time software install date.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is not a valid registry data type. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773476(v=vs.85).aspx

You have multiple choices to store DateTime, but the simplest is to use [Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_Ticks) property, which is a `long`, thus an `int64` which corresponds to `REG_QWORD`.

```
// Write
RegistryKey setKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\mySettings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
setKey.SetValue("Set", DateTime.Now.Ticks, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
setKey.Close();

// Read
RegistryKey getKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\mySettings");
var date = new DateTime((long)getKey.GetValue("Set"));
getKey.Close();
```

[image]

Here is a complete alternative to your code:

```
private bool HandlemyRegistry()
{
    const string RegKey = @"SOFTWARE\mySettings";
    const string ValueKey = "FirstRun";

    var date = DateTime.Now.Date;

    var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegKey);
    if (key is null)
    {
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        key.SetValue(ValueKey, date.Ticks, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
    }
    else
    {
        date = new DateTime((long)key.GetValue(ValueKey, date.Ticks));
    }
    key.Close();

    return (DateTime.Now - date).Days <= 20;
}
```

Comment: there is no error in above code.
but I am confused now which value we can compare in below else if condition 

`else if ((DateTime.Now - firstRunDate).Days > 20)
        return false;
    return true;`

Comment: There are many errors in your code. Mine is working. I really don't understand what you actually want to achieve, but I'l try in an instant.

Comment: I want to create function for inserting installation date of software i.e firstdate. everytime when I run application it will check registry date value i.e firstdate with todays date with validity of 20.

Lets say if I install application on 1 april 2019 till 20 april application will run smoothly. on 21 april it will popup message that your application is expired.

Comment: Which VS and c# version are you using?

Comment: Then use `== null` instead of `is null`. But why do you stick with that old version?